# Scrape text from a tooltip contained in an ajax powered popup box

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I know similar questions were asked before, but none seems to work for this particular situation. I ran into it on several sites, so for this question I chose at random [the first page of SO's own tags list.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)

If you look at the first entry on the first page, you see this:

[image]

Which displays the beginning of tag description, total number of questions and the number of questions asked today and this week.   This information is easily selected:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/tags')
```

Focusing, for example, on the `JavaScript` tag:

```
dat = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'week')]/ancestor::div[5]/div/div[1]/span/parent::*")
for i in dat:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
    javascript× 1801272
JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed language used for both client-side and server-side scripting. Its pri…
703 asked today, 4757 this week
```

Now it gets more complicated (at least for me): If you hover over the `JavaScript` tag, you get this popup box:

[image]

The box has the full tag description, and the (rounded) numbers of questions and watchers. If you hover over the “1.2m watchers” element, you see this tooltip:

[image]

This is the url for the call for this particular box:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/popup?_=1556571234452
```

That target item (as well as the total number of questions) is contained in the `title` of a `span` in this html:

```
<div class="-container">
<div class="-arrow js-source-arrow"></div>
<div class="mb12">
        <span class="fc-orange-400 fw-bold mr8">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon va-text-top iconFire" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M7.48.01c.87 2.4.44 3.74-.57 4.77-1.06 1.16-2.76 2.02-3.93 3.7C1.4 10.76 1.13 15.72 6.8 17c-2.38-1.28-2.9-5-.32-7.3-.66 2.24.57 3.67 2.1 3.16 1.5-.52 2.5.58 2.46 1.84-.02.86-.33 1.6-1.22 2A6.17 6.17 0 0 0 15 10.56c0-3.14-2.74-3.56-1.36-6.2-1.64.14-2.2 1.24-2.04 3.03.1 1.2-1.11 2-2.02 1.47-.73-.45-.72-1.31-.07-1.96 1.36-1.36 1.9-4.52-2.03-6.88L7.45 0l.03.01z"/></svg>
            <span title="1195903">1.2m</span> watchers
        </span>

        <span class="mr8"><span title="1801277">1.8m</span> questions</span>

        <a class="float-right fc-orange-400" href="/feeds/tag/javascript" title="Add this tag to your RSS reader"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconRss" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M1 3c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3zm14.5 12C15.5 8.1 9.9 2.5 3 2.5V5a10 10 0 0 1 10 10h2.5zm-5 0A7.5 7.5 0 0 0 3 7.5V10a5 5 0 0 1 5 5h2.5zm-5 0A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 3 12.5V15h2.5z"/></svg></a>
</div>
        <div>JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed language used for both client-side and server-side scripting. Its primary use is in rendering and manipulating of web pages. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its various dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript and Google-Apps-Script). <a href="/questions/tagged/javascript">View tag</a></div></div>
```

What I can’t figure out is how to put all this information together so as to get to an output (or a dataframe) which looks something like this, for all the tags mentioned in that first page:

```
Tag: JavaScript
Total questions: 1801277 #or whatever it is at the time this is performed
Watchers: 1195902 #same
.
.
etc.
```

To preempt possible comments, please let me add: I’m aware that SO has an API for searches like this, but (i) as I mentioned, I chose SO’s tags page at random and I would like to solve this issue as generically as possible; (ii) if I understand correctly, [this cannot be done with the SO API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317889/stack-exchange-api-obtaining-the-tag-watchers-count); and (iii) even if it could, I would still like to learn how to do it using scraping techniques.

Comment: so you ignore the rounded number of questions and keep only the raw? Can you not generate a list of dictionaries for example?

Comment: @QHarr - yes, the rounded number is really irrelevant. I myself couldn't generate either a list of dictionaries (or anything like that), hence the question for those who know better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following constructs the minimum url needed to retrieve that info and then extracts the required info from those urls, and inserts into variables which are inserted as a list, `row`, into a final list `results`. That final list is converted to a dataframe at the end.

You can loop all pages with construct of

```
https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page={}
```

Not sure what you want with respect to number this week etc. as the same time periods are not reported for each tag. I will update answer if you can state how you want this handled. Looks like units can be day, week or month (2 of these).

I think the questions asked in time period week/month etc is dynamically loaded so you do not always have two measurements present. To that end I have added an `if` statement to handle this. You could keep issuing requests until you get that info by testing the `len` of `frequencies` until == 2.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/tags/{}/popup'
page_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page={}'
results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://stackoverflow.com/tags')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    num_pages = int(soup.select('.page-numbers')[-2].text)

    for page in range(1, 3): # for page in range(1, num_pages):
        frequency1 = []
        frequency2 = []
        if page > 1:
            r = s.get(page_url.format(page))
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

        tags = [(item.text, urllib.parse.quote(item.text)) for item in soup.select('.post-tag')]

        for item in soup.select('.stats-row'):
            frequencies = item.select('a')
            frequency1.append(frequencies[0].text)
            if len(frequencies) == 2:
                frequency2.append(frequencies[1].text)
            else:
                frequency2.append('Not loaded') 
        i = 0
        for tag in tags:
            r = s.get(url.format(tag[1]))
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            description = soup.select_one('div:not([class])').text
            stats = [item['title'] for item in soup.select('[title]')]
            total_watchers = stats[0]
            total_questions = stats[1]
            row = [tag[0], description, total_watchers, total_questions, frequency1[i],  frequency2[i]]
            results.append(row)
            i+=1
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Tag', 'Description', 'Total Watchers', 'Total Questions', 'Frequency1', 'Frequency2'])
```

[image]

---

Using original code combined with Selenium to ensure dynamic content loaded:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/tags/{}/popup'
page_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page={}'
results = []
d = webdriver.Chrome()

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://stackoverflow.com/tags')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    num_pages = int(soup.select('.page-numbers')[-2].text)

    for page in range(1, 3): # for page in range(1, num_pages + 1):
        if page > 1:
            r = d.get(page_url.format(page))
            WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.stats-row a')))
            soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')

        tags = [(item.text, urllib.parse.quote(item.text)) for item in soup.select('.post-tag')]
        how_many  = [item.text for item in soup.select('.stats-row a')]
        frequency1 = how_many[0::2]
        frequency2 = how_many[1::2]
        i = 0
        for tag in tags:
            r = s.get(url.format(tag[1]))
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            description = soup.select_one('div:not([class])').text
            stats = [item['title'] for item in soup.select('[title]')]
            total_watchers = stats[0]
            total_questions = stats[1]
            row = [tag[0], description, total_watchers, total_questions, frequency1[i],  frequency2[i]]
            results.append(row)
            i+=1
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Tag', 'Description', 'Total Watchers', 'Total Questions', 'Frequency1', 'Frequency2'])
d.quit()
print(df.head())
```

Comment: First - great job! Really amazing and thanks! Second, couple of comments so the answer can be accepted: the time units on the # of questions isn't important (though I don't know why SO would switch from weekly to monthly mid-stream). More importantly, there is a problem with the multi-page version; when you run it as-is, output is the same as single page version; if you change `for page in range(1, 2)` to `for page in range(1, 3)`, you get `IndexError: list index out of range` from `row = [tag[0], description, total_watchers, total_questions, frequency1[i],  frequency2[i]]`.

Comment: Page 2 typescript is the first problem because frequency 1 is not the same length as frequency2 - it has one less item

Comment: Despite the page showing how_many being len 72 in the code only 71 appear but not every time so I am wondering if that content is dynamically loaded which would make sense.

Comment: "Page 2 typescript is the first problem" - what is the world coming to if you can't even trust SO to do things right....

Comment: Lol. I think it is because that content is dynamically loaded. It worked for me before posting, then got an error, then running again. I am just updating answer now.

Comment: Mission accomplished! As usual - great job; I don't know how you do it (and when - if at all - you get to sleep :)!

Comment: The logic above can of course be used to transfer to selenium where you can be sure content is loaded.

Comment: I have added selenium version as felt incomplete. My wait condition is based on presence of all elements. You may need to test this as doesn't necessarily mean content present.  I think there shouldn't be a problem as selenium implicit wait should cover the necessary load time.

Comment: Selenium version works great. BTW, I always wondered - what determines wait times for these things? Complexity of  code? Network speed?

Comment: Can be network, server side stuff too and how the page itself updates and yes - complexity/design of page